# Accessing properties of server controls of one pages using another in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an web application using asp.net I'd like how to alter properties of server controls of one page using another Eg: my `Default1.aspx` page has a textbox with id `TextBox1` and its `visibility=true`, and my `Default2.aspx` consists of a button `Button1`. Now i need to set the visibility of `TextBox1` to false on the click of `Button1.`

Comment: You will need to pass a value from one page to another: i.e. `querystring` or `viewstate`

Comment: @KaeL query string is used to access values and i need to access and change the properties specifically visibility property of the textbox

Comment: You will need `querystring` to pass the value across pages. You will then use that value to modify the properties of the control. Same with `viewstate`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (and if you find some black magic way of doing it, SHOULD not) instantiate your pages from other pages/classes.

One thing you can do is to send a variable via HTTP (as a GET or POST variable) that you can access via the Request property in your codebehind. Use `Request.QueryString[string]` for GET variables and `Request.Form[string]` for POST variables.